# visual studio is not being updated

Tags: visual-studio, updates

My current version of Vs2019 is 16.1.3

Updating done from help -> check for updates .But it still shows the same version as the latest, however in microsoft website , the latest at the moment is Visual Studio 2019 version 16.7

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try launching the visual studio installer directly. Search the start menu for "Visual Studio Installer" and open it. It will offer you to upgrade to the latest version.